impact of time to particular event on response
I am trying to evaluate which variables have the impact on the outcome. My clinical team wants to check if time to particular event has an impact on the outcome. If particular event occured, then time to this event is obvious but how to set the time to particular event if this event didn't occur. If I set time to particular event to the maximum time on treatment for those without event then automatically I got that there is an impact

I added some tags to your question that may help you get answers. By the way, it is your independent (or predictor) variable that is censored, not your dependent variable.

I don't think setting time to its maximum when there is no event is a good idea.
One way to deal with this is to first model event vs. no event and then, in the subset of the data where there is an event, measure time to event.
You say the team wants to check time to event, which would only be the second group, but it's hard to see how they could not be interested in the other group, as well.
There are other ways to deal with this, but the above is pretty simple, as long as you have enough people with the event.
Googling found an article from MIT by Rigobon Estimation with Censored Regressors but my computer would not let me download it because of "internal security issues".  I have no idea what the issue is, but the article sounds on point. Another article is Austin & Hirsch (2004) Estimating linear regression in the presence of a censored independent variable in Statistics in Medicine

(+1) @Kate, the principle problem is called censoring (you know a value is at least a certain value, but not exactly what).

@FransRodenburg yeah, I have experience with time-to-event outcomes, i.e. when outcome is time to event while dependent variable is binary but not vice versa, i.e. when outcome is binary while dependent variable is time-to-event

Time to event independent variables seem much rarer, and there is relatively little written about them.
